# What are some efficient ways to use a Krogan?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In multiplayer, you can unlock a Krogan. The Krogan has a special melee where he charges, but this leaves him quite vulnerable.

What are some efficient ways to play as a Krogan? Should one focus on powers over weapons? How should one use a Krogan in Silver and Gold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Krogan Sentinel and Solider are considered "rare" items for a reason. Their unique Krogan abilities are a charging melee and [rage](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rage_%28power%29).

> Rage is an ability that triggers when the krogan performs 2 successful
>   melee kills within 30 seconds. this grants the krogan increased
>   protection for 30 seconds. this effect can be renewed for each
>   additional melee kill within the next 30 seconds.

Combining this with [Tech Armor](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tech_Armor) (Sentinel) or [Fortification](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Fortification) (Solider) allows the Krogan to become a bullet sponge tank. The power cool down penalty has less of an impact on a melee heavy game play strategy. That being said focus on weapons over powers. Finally, the Tech Armor explosion helps minimize the melee vulnerability.

Comment: after playing around with a krogan soldier for a while, I have to add that rage + fortification (with all the proper defense choices) definitely does not make you invincible on silver or gold :P